# How to edit "Author" column in a document libary using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powershell

I copied files from a document library to another using powershell. But in new document library, for all files, created by column is the system account. I want to update this value to author of the original file. When I try to edit using powershell is gives me ""Author" is a ReadOnly property." error.

Here is a piece of code. How can I edit the author property?

```
$sWeb=Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$sList=$sWeb.Lists | ?{$_.Title -eq $sourceLibraryTitle}

$dWeb=Get-SPWeb $destinationWebURL
$dList=$dWeb.Lists | ?{$_.Title -eq $destinationLibraryTitle}

$RootFolder=$sList.RootFolder
$RootItems=$RootFolder.Files
$counter=0
#$RootItems.Count

foreach($RootItem in $RootItems)
{

    Write-Host   $RootItem.Title " copying..."
    $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary() 
    $dFile = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($RootItem.Name, $sBytes, $true) 
    #Write-Host $RootItem.Author

    $replacedUser=$sWeb.EnsureUser($RootItem.Author)       
    $fieldUserValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($sWeb.RootWeb, $replacedUser.ID, $replacedUser.LoginName);
    #Write-Host $fieldUserValue

    $RootItem.Author=$fieldUserValue

    $dFile.Update()   

    $counter=$counter+1
    Write-Host $counter " item copied"    

}
```

Comment: I notice that you are taking items from $sList, and updating the items of $sList, with its own value, is it what you are trying.?

Comment: you are setting the author of $RootItem -> which belongs to $sList (Source) and then finally without setting any value to the destination item, you are updating the $dFile -> which belongs to $dList.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$dWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = "true";` because before updating the read-only fields, we need to enable this, if this doesn't work for you then instead of the `$dFile.Update()`, try with `$dFile.UpdateOverwriteVersion();`

Above all the mentioned approaches, please check the logic which you have implemented, I guess the problem is in the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation .I followed this Powershell command to change the authors for all SharePoint items.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/78526b32-430c-4b62-80ea-87d968e561d2/edit-created-by-column-using-power-shell?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tadd/archive/2008/05/22/updating-the-created-by-and-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx

Comment: Please add details from the lnks to your answer. As it is written now it will be to no help in the future if the link breaks

Answer (score 0):

Call the following code:

```
$newItem = $dFile.Item
$newItem["Author"]=$fieldUserValue
$newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

instead of:

```
$RootItem.Author=$fieldUserValue
$dFile.Update()
```

`UpdateOverwriteVersion` is the only method of `SPListItem` that allows overwriting of *Modified*/*Modified by* (aka *Editor*)/*Created*/*Created by* (aka *Author*) fields.

Also, call it on the new `SPListItem` object (i.e. `$dFile.Item` in your case) and not on the `SPFile` object.